# Search Filter Join with 3 tables based on particular condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables namely t1,t2,t3 .

**Table : t1**
Description : Store Uploaded Files

```
id | filename | display_filename | uploaded_path
```

**Table : t2**
Description : Store Replaced Files
Replaced Files means  i have added an option for replacing uploaded files. So the files from t1 will moved to t2

```
id|fileid | filename | display_filename | uploaded_path
```

**Table : t3**

Description : Log Details of visited Files

```
id|fileid|userid|action|access_time|ip_Address|is_backup(0 /1)
```

`is_backup` column is used for knowing whether the file visited  is older or not

I have added a view for listing log details with filter by `display_file_name`

My problem is

if `is_backup` value is `0` then i wanted to get `display_filename` from **t1** otherwise **t2**

How can i write query for retrieving the filter data ?

```
SELECT t3.* FROM t3  
LEFT JOIN t1  
ON t1.id = t3.fileid 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON  t2.fileid  = t3.fileid
WHERE t1.display_filename LIKE '%abc%';
```

The above query will only check in table **t1**
I want to check in **t2** based on `is_backup` value

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, although I haven't tried it but I think it will work.

```
SELECT al.* FROM t3  
LEFT JOIN t1  
ON t1.id = t3.fileid 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON  t2.fileid  = t3.fileid
WHERE IF(t3.is_backup = 0, t1.display_filename ,t2.display_filename ) LIKE '%abc%';
```

Let me know if this works for you..!!!